# swfdotnet library reference issue in vs2010

Tags: .net, reference, flash

I am creating an windows forms app using vs2010, framework 4.0, C#. I am adding reference of swfdotnet library's three dll files, include them in the code, intellisense is also the showing its classes, methods and properties.
But when i run the program it gives following warning and program doesnt work.

> The referenced assembly "SwfDotNet.IO" could not be resolved because
>   it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently
>   targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please
>   remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.

Should i need to add some other files. HelP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message because System.Web assembly is not part of the Client Profile.
You should switch your project target framework to ".NET Framework 4.0" instead of ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile".
Another (but not recommended) way is manual deploying of System.Web.dll with your project

Comment: Thanks. In the project properties i changed the Target Framework ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4". Success!